# How to use feof and ferror for fgets (minishell in C)

Tags: c, fgets, feof, ferror

I've written this minishell but I'm not sure I'm making a correct control of the errors. I know fgets can return feof and ferror (http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/)
but I don't know how to use them.

I've checked if fgets returns a null pointer (which indicates the content of the buffer is inditerminate) but i would like to know how to use feof and ferror.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    #include <string.h> 
    #include <stdbool.h>    
    #define LINE_LEN  50
    #define MAX_PARTS  50 
    int main ()
    {
    char* token;
    char str[LINE_LEN];
    char* arr[MAX_PARTS];
    int i,j;
    bool go_on = true;

    while (go_on == true){
        printf("Write a line:('quit' to end) \n $:");
        fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);

        if (str==NULL) {
            goto errorfgets;
        } else {
            size_t l=strlen(str);
            if(l && str[l-1]=='\n')
                str[l-1]=0;

            i=0;
            /* split string into words*/
            token = strtok(str, " \t\r\n");
            while( token != NULL ) 
            {
                arr[i] = token;
                i++;
                token = strtok(NULL," \t\r\n");
            }

            fflush(stdin);

            /* check if the first word is quit*/
            if (strcmp(arr[0],"quit")==0)
            {
                printf("Goodbye\n");
                go_on = false;
            } else {

                for (j=0; j < i; j++){
                printf("'%s'\n", arr[j]);       
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
    errorfgets:
        printf("fgets didn't work correctly");
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: @Digital_Reality: one reasonable situation for using `goto` is error handling.

Comment: @MichaelBurr that can be handled by calling some cleanup function. Isn't it?

Comment: So, if I change it to if (!fgets){ ....}, how should I handle possible errors with feoh and ferror?

Comment: @Digital_Reality: maybe, but often `goto` is really the cleanest way (at least arguably) to handle errors.  In a function like in the example where there's only one error path it might not be a big deal, but it's pretty common to use an idiom of jumping to an error handling block on any error condition as a general coding style. See http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/04/27/using-goto-for-error-handling-in-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your test:

```
fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);

[...]

if (str==NULL) {
    goto errorfgets;
}
```

is wrong. The `str` parameter is passed by value and cannot be modified by `fgets()`. Instead, you should be checking the value returned by `fgets()` (returns `NULL` on EOF or error).

Regarding your specific question: `fgets()` does not "return" `feof` or `ferror`. Both `feof()` and `ferror()` are actually functions (see the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ferror.3.html)). You would use this as follows:

```
if (!fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin)) {
    /* fgets returns NULL on EOF and error; let's see what happened */
    if (ferror(stdin)) {
        /* handle error */
    } else {
        /* handle EOF */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);
>
> if (str==NULL) {
>     goto errorfgets;
> }
> ```

That's not how you check the return value of `fgets`. What's more, in your code `str` will never be `NULL` by definition. You want something like:

```
if (!fgets(....)) }
    /* error handling. */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use feof like this.

```
#open a file
fd = fopen (testFile,"r+b");

#read some data from file 
fread (&buff, 1, 1, fd);
..
..
..
#To check if you are at the end of file
if (feof (fd))
{
    printf("This is end of file");
}else{
    printf("File doesn't end. Do continue...");
}
```